# Is Grails suitable for complex applications?

Tags: web-applications, grails, groovy

Our organization is planning to use Grails to realize a complex
application with a REST interface. I have concerns on the scalability
of the framework, given that:

- domain classes will for sure make heavy use of polymorphism. I heard people have trouble with inheritance in Grails, for instance [because of this problem on JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3766).
- Trees of objects will be saved in the database. In GORM this would be
  something like:

  ```
  class Node
  {
    static def hasMany = [children: Node]
  }
  ```

  I thought we could benefit of cascading operation to manage dependencies, but I am not sure how it would work in this case.
- the database is supposed to grow to store millions of objects
  and should work with Oracle, SQL Server and PostgreSQL. How realistic is it to count on Grails DB mapping to have this compatibility for free?
- we plan to leverage custom domain constraints to check
  the consistency of domain objects. But I have the feeling that what you can do in a validator is limited (I am not sure if you can, for instance, load a set of other objects)
- business logic implemented in services will be multi-threaded

Most examples in books and on the web show very simple
application with CRUD operation on independent sets of objects.

I am afraid that I end up using a very small subset of the feature of
Grails when the application grows, as scaffolding, web flows, ajax, or
even the DB schema generated by domain classes may not correspond
exactly to the needs of my application.

Has anybody experience to share on using Grails for such an
application?

Comment: For #3, I have an app with 35 million rows and some medium level processing. The biggest issue was not grails, but database tuning. Whenever I ran into a wall about performance, there was one or the other plugin that helped (executor and quartz plugin being the most helpful) and from what I have read on the net, performance wise, Grails is quite capable of doing very well and unless you are running the next twitter/facebook you need not bother...:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> domain classes will for sure make heavy use of polymorphism. I heard
>   people have trouble with inheritance in Grails, for instance because
>   of this problem on JIRA.

Inheritance has improved in Grails 2.0. See the section on [Abstract Inheritance](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/introduction.html). The issue mentioned in the JIRA bug reported can be worked around via declaring the property as transient.

> Trees of objects will be saved in the database. In GORM this would be something like:

Self referential relationships are fine. For more info, see Grails in Action chapter 3.

> the database is supposed to grow to store millions of objects and should work with Oracle, SQL Server and PostgreSQL. How realistic is it to count on Grails DB mapping to have this compatibility for free?

Grails is built on Hibernate, an enterprise quality ORM layer used in a variety of large J2EE applications. Depending on the types of queries you're running, you may need to use criteria and tweak things at that level, but Grails provides no inherent limitations that keep it from scaling.

> we plan to leverage the custom domain constraint mechanism to check the consistency of domain objects. But I have the feeling what you can do in a validator is limited (I am not sure if you can, for instance, load a set of other objects)

You can do cross-field validation with [this](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Constraints/validator.html). You can also define your own [custom validator classes](http://blog.swwomm.com/2011/02/custom-grails-constraints.html).

> business logic implemented in services will be multi-threaded

[It is recommended not to store state in services](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html#scopedServices), but you can use them in multi-threaded operations as there are different [scopes](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Services/scope.html) available. Of course, the onus is then on you to control concurrent access.

> Our organization is planning to use Grails to realize a complex application with a REST interface.

REST interfaces are fairly fun and easy with Grails. See [Grails in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988932) Chapter 11 or Chapter 9/13 of [Beginning Groovy and Grails from Novice to Professional](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210451).

Grails is built on tried and proven J2EE technologies like [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) and [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/). While the "out of the box" may only take you so far, the framework is configurable at various levels to meet your needs. So you're essentially asking if J2EE scales nicely. [Many people seem to say yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571910/why-is-j2ee-scalable).

Comment: Sounds like an answer written by someone in a corporate PR department, what with expressions like "It is recommended..." and "built on tried and proven technologies". I even wonder if the answer was written before the question.

Answer (score 7):

Twitter was initially released in Ruby on Rails.  Eventually they had scaleability problems and had to replace part (they chose to do it with Scala).  Recently they replaced all the rest of the Ruby/rails with Java allowing them to repurpose  9/10 of their servers because of improved efficiency.

So ask if Ruby/Rails met their needs?

Hell Yes.  They had a product out to market Very Quickly with a staff that could use a language they knew would allow them to get them there.

Later when they had buckets of money to throw at the problem, they did.

I find this to be a Great Success Story for Ruby on Rails, Java and an Agile mindset.

You will find a similar story with Grails (It may be a little less well supported but then will be closer to an architecture (J2EE) that will allow you to scale when you have to)

Answer (score 6):

(1) can be worked around with a class. Not the best solution, but might work until you need multiple inheritance. After all, you don't have to handle THAT relationship with Grails.

(2) depends on what you need. Grails and Hibernate [do support tree mapping](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html). BTW if you don't know exactly how it should behave, it's a sign you'll need to handcraft some complex behavior later anyway.

(3) It is. We do have hundreds of thousands records in DB2, MySQL, hsql and Postgre. It's Hibernate proven by time, anyway.

(4) True, you'd better not make any queries to DB in validator - at least, via GORM, as it will `flush()` the current inconsistent session. Though, I believe you still can use SQL or `withNewSession{}` in there.

(5) I see no problems with multi-threading in Services or whatever. You have a fine control over Service instantiation, like a Request-scoped Service can use a Singleton service (provided a Singleton is needed), with the latter written with the full respect to concurrent threads.

And yes, Grails is a great quick start when time-to-market is important.

Comment: What if the time to market is not as important as reliability and performance, what would you recommend than? It doesn't have to be for Groovy, just something for JVM

Comment: It's going to be subjective and thus question can be closed by moderators, but (whisper) as for me, there are only Java, Scala and Groovy for JVM. My bet would be on Scala.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to this question is to show some examples of startups built using the Grails web application framework: [**Grails Startups**](http://grails-startups.herokuapp.com/).